# How can I not affect this list in my function?

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create a function that receives a list that represent a matrix, and return a multiplied new matrix by a received number (scalar).
**The old matrix has to stay unchanged.**

I am trying this:

```
def mul_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    new_mat = mat[:]
    for row in range(len(mat)):
        for col in range(len(mat[row])):
            new_mat[row][col] = alpha * mat[row][col]
    return new_mat
```

but it seems mat is also changed. I think new_mat is a new list object that refers to the same "sub-lists" in mat, so mat is changed because its sub-lists are changed.

Am I right? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I found a solution for copying the matrix:

```
new_mat = [row[:] for row in mat]
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: You should add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Often, if a variable contains other variables (such as a list with nested lists), the inner variables are referenced via a pointer of sorts. Thus when you make a copy, you end up with what is referred to as a shallow copy where each internal object in the original and the copy are the same objects, as opposed an explicit copy at each nested layer.

To get around this, one approach is to use `deepcopy` via the `copy` module:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def mul_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    new_mat = deepcopy(mat)
    for row in range(len(mat)):
        for col in range(len(mat[row])):
            new_mat[row][col] = alpha * mat[row][col]
    return new_mat
```